# RealtimeDatabase Ler dados via Java Script

Tags: javascript, firebase

Eu tenho o seguinte JSON

```
  "colecao" : {
    "id" : {
      "subid1" : 2,
      "subid2" : 1
    }
  }
```

Uso os seguintes comandos para pegar os dados do realtime

```
    var dbrealtime = firebase.database(); 
    var query = dbrealtime.ref('colecao');
    query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val().id);

});
```

Se eu fazer vai pegar o valor "2";

```
console.log(snapshot.val().id.subid1);
```

Eu gostaria de fazer um foreach e mostrar os dois valores que possuem no id sem ter que referenciar subid1 e subid2.

Exemplo:

2

1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar Jquery para fazer isso, com o seguinte código:

```
$.each(snapshot.val().id, function(index, element) {
    console.log(element);
});
```

Você pode ler a documentação dessa função aqui:

https://api.jquery.com/each/